# Calculating summations containing binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I need to calculate the summation:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^N {N\choose{k}}\frac{x^k}{k^2}
$$

I remember that this kind of summation should be calculated by integration and\or derivative, but I am not sure,  and I don't know how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sure about $k=0$?

Answer (score 1):

If you differentiate with respect to $x$,
$\frac{x^k}{k^2}$
becomes
$\frac{x^{k-1}}{k}$.

Multiplying by $x$
and differentiating again,
this becomes
$x^{k-1}$.

Multiplying again by $x$,
this becomes $x^k$
and you can do that summation.

Inverting the operations
give an expression for the original sum.

Comment: Thanks, so I think this summation does not have a closed form answer?